# Is it possible to add a constructor to Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.DLL?

Tags: tfs

So the full error that I get is:

Exception while attempting to inspect or instantiate type Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.WindowsProvider in assembly C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\tfs\96d93be0\609f57b6\assembly\dl3\71c3ceb4\00f38a60_8f06cb01\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.DLL: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

and

Exception while attempting to inspect or instantiate type Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TfsSyncAgent in assembly C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\tfs\96d93be0\609f57b6\assembly\dl3\71c3ceb4\00f38a60_8f06cb01\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.DLL: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Both are very similar

There are two main points to this:

1)Exception while attempting to inspect or instantiate type Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.WindowsProvider

2)Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.DLL: No parameterless constructor defined for this obj

**I am making a server side event handler for tfs and I keep getting this error when i check in the item** [This is the tutorial i am following](http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2010/10/27/devleoping-and-debugging-server-side-event-handlers-in-tfs-2010.aspx). Anyone know how to fix this problem?

Note: I did NOT have the folder "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\tfs\ " for some odd reason and had to create the directory and put the dll in it. That did not fix the problem either.

Answer (score 1):

The Directory `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files` is a directory used by IIS for Web Applications like TFS. Copies of the dlls of the web app will be deployed there. So when an exception is thrown it may happen, that you get this directory as the source of the problem instead of the real TFS-Directory.

Your problems seems to be, that you do not have a **parameterless constructor** in your ISubscriber. But a parameterless constructor **is required**!

Comment: Btw. does the exception remain when you remove your own assembly?

Comment: Yep it still stays when i delete the assembly. I have all the methods and properties required by the interface.. i tried adding a constructor for the class using the interface, still the same exception.

Comment: Also, why do I not have the directory {C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\tfs\96d93be0\609f57b6\assembly\dl3\71c3ceb4\00f38a60_8f06cb01\}
? solving that might lead to the answer

Comment: Just an idea: Stop iis, delete everything below "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\tfs" and start iis again.

Comment: Don't have that directory...I only see ".../root", there's no ".../tfs".

Comment: Ok, so the error message is more senseless than I thought. Sorry - No more ideas :(

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll keep digging. :(

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot add code to someone else's code.

What are you trying to accomplish? There's probably another way to do it.

Comment: I'm trying to create a server side event handler(as given in the tutorial link). The problem comes when I check-in a item to the tfs and look at the event viewer(just log that something happened). I get the error specified. I asked to add constructor because part of the error said "No parameterless constructor defined for this object." so I guessed the implementation is incomplete in that dll maybe..